# Does it take heap to store constants (Java objects)? And how much?

Tags: java, constants, heap-memory

So in my program I have a lot of checks like:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(issuer)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new OAuth2AuthenticationException
        new OAuth2Error(code, description, null));
```

So I started to think of creating a constants class with around 6 fields like:

```
public static final OAuth2AuthenticationException ISSUER_IS_NOT_TRUSTED_EXCEPTION =
    new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error(
        INVALID_ISSUER, "Issuer is not trusted", null));
```

And now I have something like:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(issuer)
    .orElseThrow(() -> ISSUER_IS_NOT_TRUSTED_EXCEPTION);
```

My question is: is the game worth the candle? Coz in case of creating these objects every time it can take more memory in a while (if there are like a lot of concurrent users trying to access resource illegally in the momemt), but all of these objects will be destroyed by GC.

How much heap should it take to store like 6 exception and should I do this?

Comment: "How much heap should it take to store like 6 exception" negligible. But why don't you use a profiler and see for yourself?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca coz it's easier to ask here, if nobody will give me an answer I should check it by myself

Comment: It doesn't make sense to store exceptions (or most objects) like that.

Comment: @Kayaman why doesnot it?

Comment: @Kayaman more than that, it doesn't make sense to store an exception with a stack trace that's not indicative of the stack when the exception was thrown.

Comment: @AndyTurner ah I didn't even realize the plan was to use that for the **whole** program. That would obviously cause some interesting debugging issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember: exceptions should only be used to represent *exceptional* things.

If something is actually exceptional, it happens rarely, so the extra cost of creating a new object is, averaged over all the cases, basically zero, even if that object is moderately expensive to construct.

Also, an exception has a stack trace, which shows the call stack when the exception was thrown (and a cause, and suppressed exceptions, etc). It doesn't make sense for that to be stored as a constant, unless you (somehow) can guarantee that the exception is thrown in the same thread with exactly the same call stack etc.

Just create a new object.

If you're using this exception to represent something that isn't rare, it's not really exceptional. Use something else to represent this.

Answer (score -1):

> a lot of checks

What do you mean by a lot of checks? If it's happening hundreds or thousands of times a second, you will want to use a constant. When you use the constant instead, it doesn't need to create an object every time. If you're doing it only a few times, then you can just do the other way.

A good rule of thumb is that if it's being used more than 10 times (give or take), then just make it a field to avoid the extra object creation.

Edit: it also of course depends on how large the object is initially, but for a small object like in this case then the rule stands

Comment: lol, these objects are used like hundreds of times for sure, but I still don't think I should create a constant